# slash are removed from jquery ajax Feed, how Add onClick attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rss, feed

I have this headache

**The Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dvContent").append("<ul class='list'></ul>");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "file.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml){
                $(xml).find('entry').each(function(){
                var sTitle = $(this).find('title').text(); 


        // HERE I Need to add onClick attr
        // Por example (added to <a>)
        $("<li></li>").html("<a onclick='example('https://yahoo.com/');' href='http://google.com/'>" + sTitle + '</a>').appendTo("#dvContent ul");

        // but I'ts the Result: (with-out Slash and ['])

        $("<li></li>").html("<a onclick="example(" https:="" www.yahoo.com=""');'" href='http://google.com/'>" + sTitle + '</a>').appendTo("#dvContent ul");


                $("<li></li>").html("<a href='http://google.com/'>" + sTitle + '</a>').appendTo("#dvContent ul");  
            });
            },
            error: function() {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
            }
        });

    }); </script>
```

**In the line 19 aprox** `<a>` I need to add `[onclick='example('http://yahoo.com/');']`

How can I solve this?

**I realized that are deleting the Slashes and quotes**

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
$("<li></li>").html("<a class='someclass' href='http://google.com/'>" + sTitle + '</a>').appendTo("#dvContent ul");
```

you can use jquery code

```
$('.someclass').click(function(){
alert('test');
});
```